# How to stop Access from thinking my table.field in VBA is a form component?

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

So I'm writing a SQL query in VBA in Access 2010, and when this code is ran, it thinks that SupplierConnect.MailboxID is a component on a form, where it is in fact a database table (SupplierConnect) and field (MailboxID). Every time that code is ran it pops up a box asking me for input from that form component, which actually isn't one. Is there any way to get around this or code this differently?

Thanks!

```vb
' Mailbox ID
If IsNull(MailboxIDComboBox.Value) Then
Else
If firstWhere = True Then
    MailboxID = "WHERE SupplierConnect.MailboxID = '" & [Forms]![SupplierQuery]!MailboxIDComboBox.Value & "'"
    firstWhere = False
Else
    MailboxID = " AND SupplierConnect.MailboxID = '" & [Forms]![SupplierQuery]!MailboxIDComboBox.Value & "'"
End If
End If
```

Comment: You should provide more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not popping up asking you for this value because it thinks it is a form control, it is because it is undefined to the query.  It cannot find the field within query definition.  This usually happens because you do not have the proper case sensitive table or field id or the incorrect table is linked.  If you provided more code for the SQL statement you are using from beginning to end and your **Exact table structure** we can narrow down the mistake.